# Defining data types for the recursive data is not correctly worked

Tags: typescript

I'm facing a problem in defining the proper `types` for the data. I have an array of objects which have the following data and my task is to give proper `types` according to the structure of the data.

```
export const DashboardSections = [
    {
        name: 'Dashboard',
        sectionItems: [
            {
                title: 'Dashboard',
                icon: 'FaHome',
                path: adminUrl,
                type: 'link',
                active: true,
                children: [],
            },
            {
                title: 'Products',
                icon: 'FaBox',
                path: `${adminUrl}/products`,
                type: 'sub',
                active: false,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: `${adminUrl}/products`,
                        title: 'Products',
                        type: 'link',
                        active: false,
                        children: [],
                    },
                    {
                        path: `${adminUrl}/categories`,
                        title: 'Categories',
                        type: 'link',
                        active: false,
                        children: [],
                    },
                    // Tags are more specific (describe your posts in more detail)
                    {
                        path: `${adminUrl}/tags`,
                        title: 'Tags',
                        type: 'link',
                        active: false,
                        children: [],
                    },
                    {
                        path: `${adminUrl}/attributes`,
                        title: 'Attributes',
                        type: 'link',
                        active: false,
                        children: [],
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                title: 'Menus',
                icon: 'FaThLarge',
                path: `${adminUrl}/menus`,
                type: 'link',
                active: false,
                children: [],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'System',
        sectionItems: [
            {
                title: 'Appearance',
                icon: 'FaPalette',
                path: `${adminUrl}/sliders`,
                type: 'sub',
                active: false,
                children: [],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

I think the data after the root item has a recursive structure. So I have defined `types` like this.

```
type link = 'link' | 'sub';

type rootDashItem = {
    /** Title of the root item */
    title: string;
    /** Only root item could contain a svg **/
    icon: string;
    /** Path of the root item */
    path: string;
    /** Root item could be a 'link' i.e. don't have any children(empty array) or 'sub' means has array of children. */
    type: link;
    /** Item would be active or not */
    active: boolean;
    /** Contain array of sub items */
    children: subDashItem[];
};


type subDashItem = {
    title: string;
    path: string;
    type: link;
    active: boolean;
    children: subDashItem[];
};


export type dashSection = {
    name: string;
    sectionItems: rootDashItem[];
};
```

But when I try to reuse the `type` in somewhere else

```
const items = DashboardSections.map((section: dashSection ) => {
     return section.sectionItems.filter((item: rootDashItem) => {
        if (item.active) {
            return {...item, section: section.name}
        }
    });
```

Linter is throwing an error on this line `DashboardSections.map((section: dashSection )`.

```
Error:(130, 37) TS2345: Argument of type '(section: dashSection) => rootDashItem[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { name: string; sectionItems: { title: string; icon: IconType; path: string; type: string; active: boolean; children: { path: string; title: string; type: string; active: boolean; children: never[]; }[]; }[]; }, index: number, array: { ...; }[]) => rootDashItem[]'.
  Types of parameters 'section' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '{ name: string; sectionItems: { title: string; icon: IconType; path: string; type: string; active: boolean; children: { path: string; title: string; type: string; active: boolean; children: never[]; }[]; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'dashSection'.
      Types of property 'sectionItems' are incompatible.
        Type '{ title: string; icon: IconType; path: string; type: string; active: boolean; children: { path: string; title: string; type: string; active: boolean; children: never[]; }[]; }[]' is not assignable to type 'rootDashItem[]'.
          Type '{ title: string; icon: IconType; path: string; type: string; active: boolean; children: { path: string; title: string; type: string; active: boolean; children: never[]; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'rootDashItem'.
            Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'link'.
```

**What I'm doing wrong? What is a better way to define types for the recursive structure?**

**Full Code:**

```
const adminUrl = "http://localhost:3000/admin";


//#region Types

type link = 'link' | 'sub';

type subDashItem = {
    title: string;
    path: string;
    type: link;
    active: boolean;
    children: subDashItem[];
};



type rootDashItem = {
    /** Title of the root item */
    title: string;
    /** Only root item could contain a svg **/
    icon: string;
    /** Path of the root item */
    path: string;
    /** Root item could be a 'link' i.e. don't have any children(empty array) or 'sub' means has array of children. */
    type: link;
    /** Item would be active or not */
    active: boolean;
    /** Contain array of sub items */
    children: subDashItem[];
};




export type dashSection = {
    name: string;
    sectionItems: rootDashItem[];
};
//#endregion Types


//#region Item Structure
export const DashboardSections = [
    {
        name: 'Dashboard',
        sectionItems: [
            {
                title: 'Dashboard',
                icon: '',
                path: adminUrl,
                type: 'link',
                active: true,
                children: [],
            },
            {
                title: 'Products',
                icon: '',
                path: `${adminUrl}/products`,
                type: 'sub',
                active: false,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: `${adminUrl}/products`,
                        title: 'Products',
                        type: 'link',
                        active: false,
                        children: [],
                    },
                    {
                        path: `${adminUrl}/categories`,
                        title: 'Categories',
                        type: 'link',
                        active: false,
                        children: [],
                    },
                    // Tags are more specific (describe your posts in more detail)
                    {
                        path: `${adminUrl}/tags`,
                        title: 'Tags',
                        type: 'link',
                        active: false,
                        children: [],
                    },
                    {
                        path: `${adminUrl}/attributes`,
                        title: 'Attributes',
                        type: 'link',
                        active: false,
                        children: [],
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                title: 'Menus',
                icon: '',
                path: `${adminUrl}/menus`,
                type: 'link',
                active: false,
                children: [],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'System',
        sectionItems: [
            {
                title: 'Appearance',
                icon: '',
                path: `${adminUrl}/sliders`,
                type: 'sub',
                active: false,
                children: [],
            },
        ],
    },
];

//#endregion Item Structure

// Challenge is to take those root items which are active with its corresponding section title
const items = DashboardSections.map((section: dashSection ) => {
     return section.sectionItems.filter((item: rootDashItem) => {
        if (item.active) {
            return {...item, section: section.name}
        }
    });

});

console.log(items);
```

[Live link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=131&pc=20#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwLYEswFUBOAbGBeGAIgAsooAHALgHprsRg5tiRpKBmABm%20sVTEIBuAFCjaAYkwBTAOYpwMACoBPclIiioqqTGxoA1vhgByPWH3GYAHxMQArgCNjI4VrUx7DgCJwIxAJJQUkhGAN7CAJBQKFDYUpQeUJhoMiIR5HBQxAnQyWCpkW7xugZpcMDRAG7FDiAgcXBgacDEKNgI0mA5jj5%20gcEA2gC6IgC%20LpraMJh1UL0BQSEE4RHUAFRrSjFxMCAAZjBZOjMgsDHBMGvUhdvFuSlp65sA8mDYytOzMOchoHbtMFAYCgcDQ8A8lRklyukRQQJySQekSeMAACpliLsDkdPqdvotLtd0hiEXkCqsNjAAEpfH6AkD-BAwBw6OAmMwWb4AOikXJgCHAxlgxDg1XgYA%20LTaHSkYAAFMFyFp4JhMHBlABKXaYWyOSxIKSNCAwEXGuCq9VYwGtdqdPkwqLaBIcx6U-ohADuDIBLPgFRQYpAOrAeId5SqNTqDSayMpAGFwCCwea1R99h5HPjgsaHVLbbLut5fAtBiNhONRJWpAAPchB2BFfnFgDKUn9CmWkTAcANpKREQgbei4HdEASJzmxfdwzGIgksplcgUKjUGjE1EksnkYBg7pgzaSdgqdmkwhrdcwsCB0Bg81q5oQrfbkCMA0iKwi3d7JjvIAfxgAGkiAch23UcEjfCIoI-KDoliYpjF-f8gKgqC4XABJjEA4CoIyLIEj4NAsGwFDUKKTCOWw1CInDANikPKRSKgvMZS6GBhiY0YmJgqJbkw1EZgQI8oAgKjUPQtisKY4l8JgAADAASUJCIwHBRmochBOEiA5Ok8jdScaTaOqBI9iYQdpJYzoIJw6DbNwkl5KUlTiPUzSQCEiodOk2C%20JMASPO0sTqP00wDGC1DjOKMzsAs%20yIisgt2KGHyuPsniHNkxTlOQIi1OoRgghkIMUHUXT4rguJMLjTJZBK9QItgp12XCnyaP9EyYBiuLqOYm1WIglL7LS3raCUOAZDNaQYCQIMdAgNRgBQPY4RgOUEHUYBkl9ZQGR1OtoGNMFZumjak2wDV0vivDsicnL%20Fc6gQUm8ret4%20DMMUCbRLa0LKLaqLTPMxj4sStiOOGnyMpk27spc-LMkRBw7CCbyKr84wAEEyG2lGGt%205qwvMRr2ojIHYpBt6wcG1LpKG1CRrskKMYAWVlOwftsiTMIim6Ejh3LVOwdSDTADnXrIwn-tswGuuByz%20us5LONI%20mRo-L8EObZRoGCMTB2fcD2JwnjKoQzHyDUc1GmAKQIu5kxeccgWHvyiA9A2zA0ZCwnPAi2Xusp1DqeVnDGbVoCy2EecwEXbddwJA9MGEk8pHXGA4xFbA4nyHQUGNKAQEOOB9B0LJWGOWlFmND1WhaFVWQ6nQPRiTEYmNUBVXUOtY5SDxQIUM3hGvM5q6MJDMEfAfIC5JA4HIOU5QN4c2IQFtp5gLU8AAPhgFZpikKATx3Zfty5U%20R2rrkVuwIJMEXn5x1meZ3S33f94iZa1p%20Lkoq1D%20IjSCPpgHcoQuTgJ%20ABfuz4cjTy5JrUYwFEERFGBqFwqCXDXnqLyegMg5Q-AgGgoAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to annotate the type of `DashboardSections`:

```
export const DashboardSections: Array<dashSection> = [/*...*/]
```

And then fix the filter callback in `section.sectionItems.filter((item: rootDashItem) => ...`. The filter function should return a `boolean`. So you probably want to filter by `item.active` and then `map` again to transform the item as needed.

[Here's the code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwLYEswFUBOAbGBeGAIgAsooAHALgHprsRg5tiRpKBmABm+sVTEIBuAFCjaAYkwBTAOYpwMACoBPclIiioqqTGxoA1vhgByPWH3GYAHxMQArgCNjI4VrUx7DgCJwIxAJJQUkhGAN7CAJBQKFDYUpQeUJhoMiIR5HBQxAnQyWCpkW7xugZpcMDRAG7FDiAgcXBgacDEKNgI0mA5jj5+gcEA2gC6IgC+LpraMJh1UL0BQSEE4RHUAFRrSjFxMCAAZjBZOjMgsDHBMGvUhdvFuSlp65sA8mDYytOzMOchoHbtMFAYCgcDQ8A8lRklyukRQQJySQekSeMAACpliLsDkdPqdvotLtd0hiEXkCqsNjAAEpfH6AkD-BAwBw6OAmMwWb4AOikXJgCHAxlgxDg1XgYA+LTaHSkYAAFMFyFp4JhMHBlABKXaYWyOSxIKSNCAwEXGuCq9VYwGtdqdPkwqLaBIcx6U-ohADuDIBLPgFRQYpAOrAeId5SqNTqDSayMpAGFwCCwea1R99h5HPjgsaHVLbbLut5fAtBiNhONRJWpAAPchB2BFfnFgDKUn9CmWkTAcANpKREQgbei4HdEASJzmxfdwzGIgksplcgUKjUGjE1EksnkYBg7pgzaSdgqdmkwhrdcwsCB0Bg81q5oQrfbkASAEELcoADwIFtD7cAPiMAZIhWCJu17Ew7xAB9jAAGkiAc-xHRYxxgYCIgw0CMOiWJimMKCYPgjCMLhcAEmMOCEIwjIsgSPg0CwbAiOIopyI5SjiIicMA2KQ8pGYjC8xlLo0KGATRgErColucjURmBAjygCAOOI0iRIogTiVomAAAMABJQnojAcFGahyHkxSIB0zTWN1JxNO46oEj2JhB00oTOgSdDOKk6iSV0gyjMY0zzJABSKiszTsJkkw5LCyyVM42zTAMRLiMc4oXOwNyqOIjyC1EqKJNyiJfK07IAsM5AGJM6hGCCGQgxQdRrJK6TcPIuNMlkJr1DS7CnXZVKoq4-0nJgLKcs4wSbWEryxJK4rptoJQ4BkM1pBgJAgx0CA1GAFA9jhGA5QQdRgGSX1lAZHU62gY0wW2zazqTbANRKsqaIq-Sqv4YLqBBdbWum9q4nIxQ1uUkbkvYkaMuc1z+La-KROGIqos+-yfqC2rMkRBw7CCSK2pwsGTFfMhLsJvrocGlLzH60aIwR7KkZBlH5vR3KFuIpbMNy0m8IAWVlOwodytTyLSr6Emx6rjOwUyDTAMXgZYunYdy+GJsR9zZs8wqqL5nmltA8C8ObZRoGCFTB2fUcvKoqTBfI19yDUc1GmAKQ0slkxpaxwL5f+iA9DOzBiaSunPDS7XJrZvL9YKtGjeYk34LLYR5zARdt13AkD0wRSTykdcYDjEVsDifIdBQY0oBAQ44H0HQslYY5aRQmAPVaFoVVZMadA9GJMRiY1QFVdQ6xzlIPCQndBeEa8zi7ggCMwR954gLkkDgcg5TlO3hxEn8-CfY+YC1PBAJWaQoBPHcj+3Lkn+Q7MEK5I7sCCTA5Tpa+sxIC5Bld6GEd57z-gSABcpQhcjgT8WCc9nw5Hnlyc2owNQajGFg0Q156i8noDISB2YsFAA)

Comment: After annotate `export const DashboardSections: dashSection[]` linter is overriding all properties. But don't know why We did it? What approach you would take to define types for the given structure?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "linter is overriding all properties." I updated my answer and added a link to some code corrections.